# Error when compiling Typescript Code to Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, pixi.js

I am trying to create a simple PixiJS game using Typescript as the code base. I then compile the typescript to Javascript using "npx tsc" and finally in my html file I reference the newly created/updated javascript file from the typescript.

The error I get is "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
at index.js:25:23" after compiling typescript and trying to run the html in browser.
Here's the Javascript code:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const PIXI = __importStar(require("pixi.js"));
let app;
let player; //PLAYER "NODE"
let game_hold;
window.onload = function () {
    app = new PIXI.Application({
        width: 900,
        height: 700,
        background: '#1099bb'
    });
    document.body.appendChild(app.view);
};
```

I have tried to define "exports", I've tried to clear all the other lines of code but I still get errors

This is the config.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
       "module": "commonjs",
       "target": "ES2015",
       "noImplicitAny": false,
       "sourceMap": true,
       "outDir": "src"
   },
   
   "exclude": [ "node_modules" ],
   "include": ["src"]
}
```